# Using Regex to get values in python

Tags: python, regex

**I have this \n separated output from a command :**

```
    Check_mk version 1.2.2p2

radwin_rssi          WARN - Device received signal strength indication is -69  (rssi=-69;-50;-85;;)

radwin_uas           OK - Device uas is 0                                     (uas=0;;;;)

radwin_uptime        OK - up since Sun Jan  5 15:17:15 2014 (199d 02:29:13)   (uptime=17202553;;;;)
```

**I have to get last values of each line, contained between (), only.**

For example, there is nothing to get on line number 1, because there is no () brackets.

Similarily for line number 2 , there is blank line.

For line number 3, I should get **rssi=-69;-50;-85;;** , which is contained between () brackets.

Similarily for last line, I should not get **199d 02:29:13** but **uptime=17202553;;;;** (of course)

How to do this in python ??

Comment: What would be your expected output?

Comment: What have you attempted? **Post your code.**

Answer (score 2):

Use  lookahead and lookbehind,

```
(?<=\()[^)]*(?=\)$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iE2xM4/4)

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """
... Check_mk version 1.2.2p2
... 
... radwin_rssi          WARN - Device received signal strength indication is -69  (rssi=-69;-50;-85;;)
... 
... radwin_uas           OK - Device uas is 0                                     (uas=0;;;;)
... 
... radwin_uptime        OK - up since Sun Jan  5 15:17:15 2014 (199d 02:29:13)   (uptime=17202553;;;;)"""
>>> m = re.findall(r'(?<=\()[^)]*(?=\))', s)
>>> m
['rssi=-69;-50;-85;;', 'uas=0;;;;', 'uptime=17202553;;;;']
```

Comment: The OP only wants the last set of parentheses on any line, not just any set of parentheses.  [`\(([^)]+)\)$`](http://regex101.com/r/rT2dY0/1) is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: updated see http://regex101.com/r/iE2xM4/4